# Reading different objects from a serialized file

Tags: java, serialization

I am making different classes for certain objects that will be stored in a hardware store database. The database will be a .ser file. My question is how can I store the different objects in the file and be able to read them out separately. For example, I have classes called appliances, and smallHardwareItem that both extend from a class called items and are serializable. Both share common variables, such as an IdNumber, name, and quantity. The difference is that smallHardwareItem class has a unique variable, category and the appliances class has unique variables such as type and brand.

Is there a way when I read these files I can compare or tell whether it is an object type of appliances or smallHardwareItem? I am sorry I have no code right now, I am just trying to figure out a plan before coding it.

Comment: If you really want to use Java serialization, it will store the types of the classes that you have written out. So you can then do `instanceof` checks or even use a Visitor Pattern to determine what you have just read in.

Comment: @BoristheSpider  So as I read in the file I can read in any object that has an instanceof the type of object Im looking for? Would it be best if I create a method for each class to read that certain object. For example, have a method in my smallHardwareItem class that only reads in those items and then a method for my appliances that does the same for those items?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what process you are using to write items to a file, it's impossible to give specific recommendations. If you are using Java serialization, this is [already implemented for you](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) - it has problems; speed, size, etc. but for a beginner it might be the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you, I am in an OOPD class and we are working our way up to an actual db. As of now we are learning about using a .ser file to store objects. @BoristheSpider